# Fixing sliding window (non-roller) slider

Tags: repair, windows

I am trying to fix some sliding windows which don't slide smoothly and are not straight. After taking the windows off their rails, it turns out that the windows don't have rollers, just solid plastic slider pieces (and on at least one side of one window, the piece is missing entirely). Furthermore, unlike most sliding windows that use rollers, I don't see any screw that could be used to adjust the slider height (the only screw there doesn't affect the slider height).

1. what can I do to straighten the window?
2. are the plastic slider pieces replaceable and if so how?
3. what is the name of the plastic slider pieces? Closest I could find was [this part](https://www.reflectwindow.com/products/sliding-window-3-16-inch-nylon-glide-for-b-l-aluminum-windows?variant=29518697627766), but then "nylon glide" is not leading me to anymore information online.

[image: plastic slider piece]
[image: missing slider]
[image: tilted window]
[image: window off of track]
[image: window slider track]

Comment: It appears to be a nylon roller. If you remove the screw, you should be able to slip it out. Take it to a place that has window parts and they can match it with something you can replace the missing one with.